# Detecting link from text on Web View

Tags: swift, webview

I have RichTextEditorView on my view and when i'm adding link it appears like regular text, but highlighted... 
Question: how can I do thing, when i'm tapping highlighted link, it would process to safari and open that link.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBVj5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement this method Delegate `func richEditor(_ editor: RichEditorView, shouldInteractWith url: URL) -> Bool` and use URL

From Documents => Called when the internal UIWebView begins loading a URL that it does not know how to respond to. For example, if there is an external link, and then the user taps it

```
extension ViewController: RichEditorDelegate {


    func richEditor(_ editor: RichEditorView, shouldInteractWith url: URL) -> Bool{

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but nothing has changed. I've added this function and made it to return true but highlighted links still is tappable as regular text...

Comment: 1-  you have to write     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
2- set break point and make sure that your app enter this delegate

Comment: 1. I've written this. 2. App enter this function ONLY if i'm calling it in viewDidLoad() like this richEditor(editorView, shouldInteractWith: url!). But this opens url instantly after loading view.

Comment: no this wrong , this delegate `extension ViewController: RichEditorDelegate { `   **ViewController** should be where you imaplement it

Comment: I've added this `func richEditor(_ editor: RichEditorView, shouldInteractWith url: URL) -> Bool{
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        return true
    } `.  And nothing. Its just not enter this function